# Is there a PowerShell 3 simplified syntax for $_ comparisons?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

PowerShell 3 has a simplified syntax:
`$people | ? { $_.Name -eq 'Jane' }` can be written as `$people | ? Name -eq 'Jane'`

However, is there a simplified syntax for `$_` itself?

E.g `$names | ? { $_ -eq 'Jane' }` can't be written as `$names | ? -eq 'Jane'`.
Is there some other way to write it, or is it not supported?

Not that having `{}` matters much, but I want to understand the full picture.

Comment: ? is an alias for Where-Object, where $_ is the current object in the pipe... If you had something like $Names[2] = "Jane"; $Names[2] | ? {$_ -eq "Jane"} it would work, but I think I am also a little confused on what you want...

Comment: @AustinFrench I want to understand if there is something like `? Name -eq 'Jane'` for the case when you want to compare `$_` itself instead of its property. `? { $_ -eq 'Jane' }` would work, but that's the old syntax, I am interested in PowerShell 3 shortcut/simplified syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplified syntax in powershell 3.0 is based on parameters in Where-Object cmdlets: -EQ, -LT, -GT, etc. (named exacly like comparision operators), so it is not a "magic" but wisely chosen parameter names that mimics PowerShell's comparison operators.

Unfortunately it is not possible to reference the object itself, you have to use the old syntax (like you show in your question):

```
$names | Where { $_ -eq 'Jane' }
```

Comment: The way I understand it, `Name` maps to `-Property` parameter of `Where-Object`. Is there a value for `-Property` that means taking the object itself instead of its property?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not possible